# How to programmatically open dojox mobile combobox

Tags: mobile, combobox, dojo

I'm using a dojox/mobile/ComboBox widget and would like to programmatically open it.

Tried to use require("dijit/registry").byId("").openDropDown();
but the source comment says... "To be called only when this.dropDown has been created and is ready to display (that is, its data is loaded).", which it doesn't seem to be :(

Calling the _onClick doesn't help either.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Guy

Comment: My html looks something like this:
<datalist id="fruitDataList">
  <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DataList" data-dojo-props='id:"fruitDataList"' >
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option selected>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</datalist>
<input id='myComboBox' type="text" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ComboBox" data-dojo-props='list:"fruitDataList"' />

Comment: I'm using the latest dojo 1.8.3

Comment: This widget opens fine when clicking the textbox manually

Comment: Correction!!!
Calling ._startSearchAll(); and then .openDropDown(); works.

My problem is that it doesn't work when the combobox is disabled.
The reason for that is that on a mobile I want to prevent the keyboard from showing up. But when the widget is disabled the dropdown list doesn't get populated :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as you.

The dojox.mobile.ComboBox was causing the android keyboard to display.

My work around was to create the combobox programmatically like this:

```
            var myCombo = new ComboBox({
                store: registry.byId('your data list'),
                value: ''
            },"theDomInput");
            myCombo.startup();
```

then in my index.html I had a field with the readonly set like this:

```
<input id="theDomInput" type="text" readonly/>
```

The startup function needs to  be called before the click event of the combobox.

This works for me.  Let me know if you come up with something better.